Excel PowerQuery. Negative numbers missing hyphen-minus symbol
I have multiple Excel files that I am trying to combine via PowerQuery. These files are generated by ERP system and have the column "Expenditures" with positive/negative numbers in default format that displays negative numbers in red font without a minus symbol.
When combining them, Power Query transforms all numbers in the column "Expenditure" into positive numbers.
From what I understand Power Query does not natively detect font colors so I cannot Create a Conditional Column to Detect Red Font. Also, I cannot create a Conditional Column to Indicate that this number should be negative since in the source file there are no specific indicators.
I can solve this issue by manually changing the cell format in the source Excel file so that negative numbers are displayed with a minus sign, but I am wondering if there is a way to solve this issue on Power Query side without having to manually change cells format (due to a big number of files).
PQ code:
let
    Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\yevgen.matiukha\..."),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Name] <> "desktop.ini")),
    #"Filtered Hidden Files1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
    #"Invoke Custom Function1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File", each #"Transform File"([Content])),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invoke Custom Function1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
    #"Removed Other Columns1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns1", {"Source.Name", "Transform File"}),
    #"Removed Errors1" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Removed Other Columns1", {"Transform File"}),
    #"Expanded Table Column1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Errors1", "Transform File", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transform File"(#"Sample File")))
in
    #"Expanded Table Column1"

Thank you for any advice!

Your problem is likely due to the data in your excel files NOT being real numbers, but rather text strings. Either your ERP system is outputting numeric data as text (which seems a poor choice of output data typing), or there is an issue with how you are  getting the data into your Excel file. What type of file is the ERP system outputting? xls, xlsx, csv ?

Hi Ron! Thank you for your comment. ERP system outputs Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet (.xls).

Can you enter =ISTEXT(cell_ref) to test the data type? Or possibly share a worksheet that demonstrates the problem?

Sure, link to the example file :https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NtrxVPgFD20bJB1hp8h7Eih81e6EdmKg/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=115519766898090800116&rtpof=true&sd=true

I cannot reproduce the issue with the data you present. PQ interprets the red font numbers as negative (as it should since they are stored as "real numbers"). Please edit your question to include the Power Query code you are using to import the data table from your workbook or, preferably, include the PQ code in the workbook you uploaded.

Yes, you are right, I provided a bad example (I have deleted columns with unnecessary information). This example reproduces the isse:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AGOCA1GCrmbb3LWsrMXCE7nBA7Sh55G6/view?usp=sharing

I am out of town for a day or two. I will check back when I am at a computer.

The problem you are running into is due to an incompatibility between *.xls files and Power Query. This was reported at least four years ago to Microsoft Power BI team, so it probably won't get fixed.
Several possible solutions:

Save the file as an .xlsx file.
Change the formatting in the .xls file so the minus sign is visible.
Remove all the formatting in the .xls file.

I know of no way to solve this using Power Query alone.
I'd favor the first solution, as this will preserve the formatting from the ERP.
